# Python bs4 Неправильно вставляется значение атрибута

Tags: python, html, bs4

Через BeautifulSoup в html меняю значение атрибутов, но в одном записывается неправильно.

В коде:
`soup("tag")["attr"] = "api.php?stream_key=<?=$_GET['stream_key']?>"`

Записывает в html: `"api.php?stream_key=&lt;?=$_GET['stream_key']?&gt;"`

Как сделать корректную запись?
Спасибо

Comment: а что некорректного в записи?

Comment: Вместо < и > - &lt и &gt

Comment: Это нормально.  так экранируются символы.

Comment: Понял. А в bs4 есть способ записи без экранирования? На выходе там из html делаться php, и нужны именно такие символы. То что нашел - сделать через replace

Comment: у  меня есть подозрение, что php великолепно "съест" экранированные символы.

Answer (score 1):

Решил следующим костылем:
Словарь в ключах имеет экранированные символы, по значению их в нормальной форме.
Далее читает текст из файла, циклом делает replace, и перезаписывает файл.

```
def replace():
        symbols = {
            '&lt;': '<',
            '&gt;': '>'
        }

        with open("filename.php", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
            text = f.read()

        for i in symbols:
            text = text.replace(i, symbols[i])

        with open("filename.php", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
            f.write(text)
```

Comment: 1. мне кажется это лишней работой. 2. не следует называть свои функции именами встроенных  методов python

Comment: @strawdog, 1 - согласен, 2 - replace не встроенная функция :)

Comment: Экранирование < и > в кавычках это правильное поведение, т.к. это бы сломало структуру html, что вызывало ошибки парсера или он неправильно распарсил (т.к. парсер html не строгий и может исправить ошибки структуры). Но если это будет в php, то это нормально, т.к. тот по идеи возвращает html, а `<?=$_GET['stream_key']?>` я так понимаю для замены переменной из запроса php